# Wordpress sanitize data before saving with update_post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, sanitize

I am trying to create post options for my new WordPress template, but I don't know how I can sanitize or validate my custom post meta data before saving:

```
$data = $_POST['enablog_post_options'];

// Update the meta fields in the database.
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'enablog_post_options',$data );
```

All options (YouTube URL, text, checkbox and radio buttons) are saved with my unique meta key `enablog_post_options`.

**Update:**

`sanitize_text_field()` corrupted all my code (all checkboxes are checked when I save the post), IMHO I need more than simply `sanitize_text_field()`, because `$_POST['enablog_post_options']` has checkboxes, text fields and more.

Answer (score 4):

**First.** Assuming the `$_POST['enablog_post_options']` is an array it should be sanitized as an array, iterating each one element in a loop. Not as a string, all elements at once.

So look up into your `enablog_post_options` array and decide a data-type-dependent techinque of sanitizaion for each element. [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) can help *starting* with it.

**Now.** As you understand what data types you are really going to sanitize, I suspect it is worth mentioning the `update_post_meta()` built-in sanitization actions & custom filters you can hook to the function.

So, anyone can look up the code of the `update_metadata()` function that does the heavy lifting for `update_post_meta()` [here in the Core Metadata API source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L143).

But meanwhile, it sanitizes:

- meta key with `sanitize_key()` and `wp_unslash()`;
- meta value with `wp_unslash()` and `sanitize_meta()` (more explanation on this one follows).
- database save query with `wpdb::prepare()` called from `update_metadata()`->`wpdb::update()`;

**Sanitize with `sanitize_meta()`.**

The convenient way to additionally sanitize the [custom] post meta is via [`sanitize_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_meta). The `update_metadata()` already hooks the potentially existing custom sanitization filter you have to create into the process of meta field sanitization. This is done via `sanitize_meta()`.

It is called from `update_metadata()` like this with all your post meta parameters:

```
$meta_value = sanitize_meta( $meta_key, $meta_value, $meta_type );
```

So you can just make a custom sanitization filter to work with your post meta like this (the example from WP Codex `sanitize_meta()` description, the link above):

```
// --- sanitize_meta() call is commented out because it is called from update_metadata()
// $clean_value = sanitize_meta( 'birth-year', $user_input, 'user' );
function sanitize_birth_year_meta( $year ) {
    $now = date( 'Y' );
    $then = $now - 115; // No users older than 115.
    if ( $then > $year || $year > $now ) {
        wp_die( 'Invalid entry, go back and try again.' );
    }
    return $year;
}
add_filter( 'sanitize_user_meta_birth-year', 'sanitize_birth_year_meta' );
```

Continuing with some imagnary code, in `sanitize_birth_year_meta()` instead of `$year` you will get your `$data` content to get sanitized when the the filter is called.

Comment: What is `$meta_type` in your example?

Comment: @AntikM hey. The parameter is probably outdated as the answeri is 6 years old. I see in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_meta/) they changed `sanitize_meta()` function signature. You can refer there to understand how to use the actual API.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress standards recommend to use `wp_unslash()` for every global variable that are ($_POST ,$_GET and etc).. after that use any sanitize function according to your need.

```
$data = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['enablog_post_options'] ) );

// Update the meta fields in the database.
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'enablog_post_options',$data );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to sanitize your data:

```
$data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['enablog_post_options'] );

// Update the meta fields in the database.
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'enablog_post_options',$data );
```

Have a look at the Codex on [Validating Sanitizing and Escaping User Data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data)

Comment: Sanitize_text_field corrupt all my code (all checkboxs are checked when i save post), IMHO i need more than simply sanitize_text_field, because $_POST['enablog_post_options'] has checkboxs, text fields and more.